How to collapse all strings from a dataframe into a single column
I have a dataset where cells are occupied by strings of varied length or NAs.
I need to produce one column (say a dataframe consisting of one column) with all strings. Essentially stack all valid string answers, filtering NAs out in the process.
df.input <- data.frame(col1 = c("green potatoes","read avocados","white pepper","wise master"),
                      col2 = c("white seagull","black tank","creative pigeon","crazy socks"),
                      col3 = c("constant turmoil","ready fan",NA,"interesting collapse"),
                      col4 = c("awesome lettuce","jiggedy cabbage",NA,NA),
                      col5 = c("green potatoes","read avocados",NA,NA),
                      col6 = c("green potatoes",NA,NA,NA),
                      col7 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA)
                      )

The dataframe for output should be like:
df.output <- data.frame(colOnlyOne = c("green potatoes","read avocados","white pepper","wise master",
                                       "white seagull","black tank","creative pigeon","crazy socks",
                                       "constant turmoil","ready fan","interesting collapse",
                                       "awesome lettuce","jiggedy cabbage",
                                       "and so on for all non-NA string values...")
                        )

How do I achieve that? Preferably, using tidyverse family of functions.

Try: stack(df.input) or tidyr::pivot_longer(df.input, everything())

> data.frame(colOnlyOne = na.omit(unlist(df.input, use.names = FALSE)))
             colOnlyOne
1        green potatoes
2         read avocados
3          white pepper
4           wise master
5         white seagull
6            black tank
7       creative pigeon
8           crazy socks
9      constant turmoil
10            ready fan
11 interesting collapse
12      awesome lettuce
13      jiggedy cabbage
14       green potatoes
15        read avocados
16       green potatoes

